# Does a pointer to a virtual function still get invoked virtually?

Tags: c++, function, virtual, function-pointers

Will a function pointer to a class member function which is declared virtual be valid?

```
class A {
public:
    virtual void function(int param){ ... };
}

class B : public A {
    virtual void function(int param){ ... }; 
}

//impl :
B b;
A* a = (A*)&b;

typedef void (A::*FP)(int param);
FP funcPtr = &A::function;
(a->*(funcPtr))(1234);
```

Will `B::function` be called?

Comment: You have the code. This is one of those questions you could have answered yourself just by running the code.

Comment: because its faster to ask here than to fire up IDE, create project, code, compile, debug, etc... and it would give benefit to other, and this question / code won't lost.

Comment: @Martin: What if behavior was undefined ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It also works with virtual inheritance.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Valid code to test on [codepad](http://codepad.org) or [ideone](http://www.ideone.com/) :

```
class A { 
public: 
    virtual void function(int param){
      printf("A:function\n");
    }; 
};

class B : public A { 
public:
    virtual void function(int param){
      printf("B:function\n");
    };  
}; 

typedef void (A::*FP)(int param);

int main(void)
{
  //impl : 
  B b; 
  A* a = (A*)&b; 

  FP funcPtr = &A::function; 
  (a->*(funcPtr))(1234);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function will be called, as you just try to invoke inherited function.

Answer (score 0):

The best test for that thing is to make the methods in the class A a pure virtual method. In both cases (with or without pure virtual methods), B::function will be called.